# Does $L^2((0, 1])$ contain $(L^\infty((0, 1]))^2$ as $L^\infty((0, 1])$-modules?

Tags: modules, von-neumann-algebras

Does $L^2((0, 1])$ contain $(L^\infty((0, 1]))^2$ as $L^\infty((0, 1])$-modules?
Here $L^\infty((0, 1])$ is just treated as a ring.

Comment: I think $(-f\chi_A, \chi_A)$ is a nontrivial element in the kenel of the map you defined, where $A:=\{x \in (0, 1]: |f(x)| \leq M \}$ has nonzero measure for some $M$ large enough.

Comment: Bingbing, my comment wasn't thoughtful. I erased it. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Bingbing, I posted below a new answer that gives a bit more than you asked for. Accordingly I erased a former answer, which despite being correct was ad-hocish in nature and gave less.

Comment: Maybe I should say: the new answer I gave is a respond to a comment of Bingbing to my previous answer which is now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be asking whether there exists an injective $L^\infty([0,1])$-module map $(L^\infty([0,1]))^2\to L^2([0,1])$. The answer is "NO".
In fact, I claim that every finitely generated submodule of $L^2([0,1])$ is actually generated by a single element and it is isomorphic to $L^\infty([0,1])\cdot\chi_A$ for some measurable $A\subset [0,1]$.
This follows from the three claims below.

**Claim 1:** For every $f\in L^2([0,1])$ there exists $\phi_f\in L^\infty[0,1]$ such that $\phi_f f=|f|$.

*Proof:* For $t$ such that $f(t)=0$ define $\phi_f(t)=0$.
Otherwise define $\phi_f(t)=\overline{f(t)}/|f(t)|$.

**Claim 2:** Every finitely generated submodule of $L^2([0,1])$ is generated by a single element.

*Proof:* For the module generated by $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ consider the element $f=\sum \phi_{f_i}f$.

**Claim 3:** The module generated by a single element $f$ is isomorphic to $L^\infty([0,1])\cdot\chi_{\{t\mid f(t) \neq 0\}}$.

*Proof:* The kernel of the map $L^\infty([0,1])$ to $L^2([0,1])$ given by $1\mapsto f$ is clearly $L^\infty([0,1])\cdot\chi_{\{t\mid f(t)= 0\}}$.

**Corollary:** There is no injective $L^\infty([0,1])$-module map $\phi: (L^\infty([0,1]))^2\to L^2([0,1])$.

*Proof:* Since the image of $\phi$ is finitely generated it could be injected further into $L^\infty([0,1])$, thus we obtain a map $(L^\infty([0,1]))^2\to L^\infty([0,1])$. We conclude by the fact that for every commutative unital ring $R$, an $R$-module map $\psi:R^2\to R$ cannot be injective: either $\psi=0$ or the nonzero element $(\psi(0,1),-\psi(1,0))$ is in its kernel.

**Remark:** Note that it follows that for every $n\geq 2$, there is no injective $L^\infty([0,1])$-module map $(L^\infty([0,1]))^n\to L^2([0,1])$.

Comment: Uri, thank you very much for considering the further questions and sharing them with me. This helps me prove the equality that $\dim_{\mathcal{L} \mathbb {Z}} \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})=1$ when one treats  $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}$ as (purely algebraic) ${\mathcal{L} \mathbb {Z}}$-module. Here $\dim_{\mathcal{L} \mathbb {Z}}$ is Wolfgang Lueck's extended von Neuman-dimension function and $\mathcal{L} \mathbb {Z}$ is the group von Neumann algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$. (I also got some further progress to share with you last night but I got some technical trouble. Sorry about that)